# Haskell C FFI: accessing static data structures

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

I have a question about the Haskell C FFI, specifically about accessing static data structures exported by a C library.

The C library I’m wrapping has static data structures like `FOO_GEORGE` below, exported in the following fashion:

```
static struct foo_struct foo_table[] = { /* list of foo structs */ }
typedef struct foo_struct *foo_t;
foo_t FOO_GEORGE = &foo_table[0];
foo_t FOO_HARRY  = &foo_table[1];
foo_t FOO_SUSAN  = &foo_table[2];
/* ... */
```

The value I need in my Haskell library is the address of the `foo_struct` (`&foo_table[n]`), that is, the contents of `FOO_GEORGE`, which is put in an opaque newtype wrapper in the usual way (the constructors are not exported from the library, only the type):

```hs
newtype Foo = Foo { getFoo :: (Ptr Foo) }
```

This is what I’m doing now:

```hs
foreign import ccall "&FOO_GEORGE" fooGeorgeHandle :: Ptr (Ptr Foo)
FooGeorge = Foo . unsafeDupablePerformIO . peek $ fooGeorgeHandle
```

I think this is an appropriate use of `unsafePerformIO`, since the C API and implementation say that this use of `peek` is pure and has no side effects. Also, I believe that I don’t need to take any of the precautions outlined in bullet points in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html) (starting with  `{-# NOINLINE foo #-}`).

My overall question is: am I doing this right? Are the bits of analysis above correct? Is there a better or preferable way to do this? If the `foreign import` clause allowed me to do the pointer defererence, that would be nice, but it doesn’t seem to; am I missing anything? One could argue that this would be a bad feature since it could segfault if the pointer is bad — but then, the same is true of the `peek` I have to use instead, so it comes to the same thing.

Thanks!

Comment: The `unsafeDupablePerformIO` should be fine in this instance.  Can you use the CApiFFI extension?  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/ffi.html

Comment: I didn't know about `CApiFFI` (or anything else documented there), but it looks promising. I'll try it out and report back. Thanks!

Comment: This works perfectly and is what I was hoping for; I updated the question. Thanks again.

Comment: I guess I should've made an answer, but I've never used `CApiFFI` so I wasn't sure it would work.

Comment: Please consider answering your own question, instead of editing the question.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to write up the workaround for ghci?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll rewrite this as an answer and add the ghci workaround this weekend.

Comment: @RichardE.Silverman Still waiting on that answer.

Comment: Done now; sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John L. suggested the `CApiFFI` extension, which does exactly what I want: allows you to import values rather than locations. Now:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE CApiFFI #-}
newtype {-# CTYPE "foo.h" "struct foo_struct" #-} Foo = Foo { getFoo :: (Ptr Foo) }
foreign import capi "foo.h value FOO_GEORGE" fooGeorgePtr :: Ptr a
fooGeorge = Foo fooGeorgePtr
```

Another advantage is that this works regardless of whether `FOO_GEORGE` is a C variable or a preprocessor macro. The C API I’m working with uses both, and different implementations of the same API that I link to do so differently, so being independent of that is great.

However, there’s a stumbling block: `CApiFFI` doesn’t work with *ghci*! The problem is [known](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7388), and it isn’t slated to be fixed until GHC 8.0.1 (when I first wrote this, it was due for 7.10, and then was pushed forward). I have a very hacky workaround. `CApiFFI` works by generating a C library on the fly, compiling and linking the Haskell program against it. It removes the library when done; the *ghci* problem seems to be that the *.so* file is gone by the time *ghci* needs to link against it. I just grab the *.c* file during compilation before it gets deleted, then compile it myself and tell *ghci* to load it. Since I don’t change that portion of the program very often, it works out for me well enough.

My method for catching the temporary *.c* file is to start *ghci* in Emacs `compilation-mode`, with `(setq compilation-auto-jump-to-first-error t)`. Emacs sees the error and loads the *.c* file into a buffer before GHC gets around to deleting it — by the time I see it the file is gone, but I’ve got the contents in a buffer.

**Update:** `ghci -fobject-code Foo` works, but can only see the names exported from the module.